# Cypher: nodes creation issue

Tags: cypher

I am unable to create 10K nodes neither in gui interface nor in cypher shell. I did follow Neo4j Performance Tuning (https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-performance-tuning/). I am using Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS with 16GB RAM on Intel® Core™ i7 CPU @ 3.00GHz × 4. I have neo4j community version 3.4.7. I set the parameters in neo4j.conf as:

dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=8g

dbms.memory.heap.max_size=8g

dbms.memory.pagecache.size=10g

dbms.jvm.additional=-Xss8G

dbms.jvm.additional=-Xmx8G

I am using embedded installation. Even then, i am getting following error in cypher-shell:

*There is not enough stack size to perform the current task. This is generally considered to be a database error, so please contact Neo4j support. You could try increasing the stack size: for example to set the stack size to 2M, add `dbms.jvm.additional=-Xss2M' to in the neo4j configuration (normally in 'conf/neo4j.conf' or, if you are using Neo4j Desktop, found through the user interface) or if you are running an embedded installation just add -Xss2M as command line flag*

The cypher command file  is attached in text file.

[cypher-file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QbtL-P4xYxruYwGLO8l87_z2gkZPefKq/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

You should either use LOAD CSV, or execute each cypher separately.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  @Faaiz is creating a single query that just by itself is 500kb+ in size.  It looks like he pre-processed CSV or something to get to this query in the first place.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits, no i didn't preprocess any CSV to get this file. Rather, i created this file using an indigenously created automatic cypher generator to create neo4j graphs

Comment: @Faaiz yes, but you should have generated a CSV instead. By trying to do it in one giant cypher, you overload the cypher planner and force everything to be generated in memory before they can be committed. You either need to adapt to use LOAD CSV, or you need to break up your cypher into a series of smaller executions.